# Declare constants that include special character

Tags: c#

I have a string that contains special character {,[,.. as follow:

```
"[{"name":"print","next":"null","proc":"printproc","func":"null"}]"
```

To assign the constant string to a variable, I have to do the following:

```
string s = "[{\"name\":\"print\",\"next\":\"null\",\"proc\":\"printproc\",\"func\":\"null\"}]";
```

or the compiler will throw out an error. Is there a less cumbersome way to declare the constant. I have tried to use @ at the beginning of the string:

```
string s = @"[{"name":"print","next":"null","proc":"printproc","func":"null"}]";
```

But I got a compiler error as well. Saving the constant into a text file and load from it will work but it may be an overkill for me. Have anyone come across the same scenario in C# and have they come up with a work around?

Comment: Can you post error please?

Comment: For string literals started with `@`, you escape a double-quote character by using two double quotes, as in `@"[{""name""...`

Comment: The compiler has no way of telling if your quotations marks aren't supposed to be the end of the string unless you escape them.

Comment: you've got a string that contains string-metacharacters. there's no way around having to escape them...

Comment: Escaping the double-quotes with "\" is your best bet IMO. Or store the JSON in a json file.

Comment: The easiest way for me when dealing with such texts is to put them in a typed resource.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I guess this is my best option. Adding "\" or extra " is tedious as I could have hundred of lines of that pattern. Maybe storing in it a json file and read from the file to deserialize it back to the object seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using single quotes to wrap the property names/values?

e.g. `string s = @"[{'name':'print','next':'null','proc':'printproc','func':'null'}]"`

Comment: To my surprise, it actually work! I was afraid I could not deserialize it back to the object but quick test shows that it does restore the object back from the string. This is the response I was looking for when I am testing a small dataset. Awesome! Thanks Chara!

Answer (score 1):

1. you can put double qutes:

   `string s = @"[{""name"":""print""}]";`
2. Or, put `\`

   `string s = "[{\"name\":\"print\"}]";`
3. You can use this `'` instead of `"`
4. Split your data with any way then use it

Answer (score 0):

You could make a variable for each special character you want.

To show the concept, I tested this in a simple C# Console app.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string quot = "\"";
            string compound = "Now I can use " + quot + "quotation marks" + quot + " around a variable";
            Console.WriteLine(compound);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

> Now I can use "quotation marks" around a variable